# Cloud Functions vs Firebase SDK for web project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm about to start writing my Firebase Firestore calls for a React web project, and I would like to hear your opinion about using cloud functions vs the Firebase SDK.

My perspective on using the SDK is that, yes it's easier, but it's harder to test from an endpoint perspective, since there are no endpoints. I was thinking to do e2e testing with firebase-mock, if I decide to go with this approach. Another challenge I see with using the SDK, is that I will need to write the functions for the mobile app vs having 1 endpoint for both:web and mobile.

On the other hand, if I decide to go with cloud functions, I can test the endpoints but I'm concerned that the cold starts may slow down my UX. I'm reserving cloud functions just for document manipulations and transactional emails.

Thank you for your time and please correct me if my perspective is wrong.

Cheers!

Comment: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c

Comment: Thank you for the link, Doug, I'll take a look. Cheers

Comment: Your perspective is not wrong but this is the wrong forum to ask for opinions, especially with this use case as it could be a very long discussion with no real concrete answers possible. There are so many variables with what you're asking it would take a lot of back and forth to derive any real feel for a solution. I think it would be better asked over in the Firebase Google groups as it's a lot more free form.

Comment: Thank you @Jay I wasn't aware of the Firebase Google groups.